# Remove Everything including text after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a quick solution to something seemingly simple:

I want to removed everything, including text, after a specific  element in a html element.

I have :

```
<div class="main-container">
Some text and <a href="" class="classone">SOME HTML</a>. 
I also have someother text, and some more <b>html</b> 
</div>
```

I want to delete everything after "classone" element within that main container.

I have  tried `$('.main-container').nextAll().remove();` but that removes only the html.

Comment: You have said what you have. That's the input. What you want as output?

Comment: it would help if you wrapped text in ps or spans ... loose text is a bad practice

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman  "Remove Everything including text after an element"  like the  title says.

Comment: @treyBake  I don't have control over the content itself unfortunately

Comment: @codiiv You might make use of `.contents()`.

Comment: Are you trying to remove all text nodes and HTML elements within `.main-container` following `.classone`?

Comment: @guest271314 that's exact

Comment: @codiiv Found the solution and posted it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make use of `.contents()`:

```js
$(function () {
  var FoundClass = false;
  
  $(".main-container").contents().filter(function (s, el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass("classone")) {
      FoundClass = true;
      return false;
    }
    return FoundClass;
  }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  Some text and <a href="" class="classone">SOME HTML</a>. I also have someother text, and some more <b>html</b>
</div>
```

This is kinda slightly hacky because I use a flag `FoundClass`. If there's a better solution, I am always welcome. This is what I came up with jQuery's `.contents()`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks

Comment: @codiiv Glad to help you mate.

Answer (score 1):

Remove last node from the parent node, until the node you want becomes the last node of parent node.

```js
function removeAllNodesAfter (node) {
    const parentNode = node.parentNode;
    while (parentNode.lastChild !== node) {
        parentNode.removeChild(parentNode.lastChild);
    }
};

removeAllNodesAfter($('.classone')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
Some text and <a href="" class="classone">SOME HTML</a>. 
I also have someother text, and some more <b>html</b> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` they exist in the `DOM` you can remove `.classone` `.nextSibling`.

```js
const one = document.querySelector(".classone");

while (one.nextSibling) one.parentElement.removeChild(one.nextSibling);

console.log('done');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="main-container">
Some text and <a href="" class="classone">SOME HTML</a>. 
I also have someother text, and some more <b>html</b> 
</div>
```

Comment: ..my idea was the same, but I did `let cutoff = document.getElementById('second');
while(cutoff.nextSibling) cutoff.nextSibling.remove()`

Comment: For some reason, though the fiddle works perfectly, when I run my actual code in it, it  logs "done" but doesn't do the change I want. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using no loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
  const content = $(".main-container").html();
  const element = $(".main-container .classone").html();
  const index = content.indexOf(element);
  $(".main-container").html(content.substr(0, index + element.length));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
Some text and <a href="" class="classone">SOME HTML</a>. 
I also have someother text, and some more <b>html</b> 
</div>
```